# Jacobi symbol flipping and coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, jacobi-symbol

The law  of quadratic reciprocity for Jacobi symbols says if m and n are positive coprimes intergers then:

$\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) = (-1)^{\tfrac{m-1}{2}\cdot\tfrac{n-1}{2}} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \text{ or } m \equiv 1 \pmod 4,\\
-1 & \text{if } n\equiv m \equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{cases}$

In all implementations of calculating the Jacobi symbol I've seen, they just seems to ignore this coprime requirement and just turn flip the symbol.

Some examples that show this:

- http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=JacobiSymbol
- http://math.fau.edu/richman/jacobi.htm
- http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/NumberTh27JacobiSymbolAlgorithm.aspx
- http://www.planetmath.org/CalculatingTheJacobiSymbol

Why can this coprime requirement be ignored?

When implementing this, checking that the gcd would clearly slow it down.

Comment: If $\gcd(m,n)>1$ then $\left(\frac mn\right)=0$.

Comment: In an actual implementation, you can check after the loop has finished whether the final n is 1. Then the computed result is valid, otherwise the Jacobi symbol is zero.

Comment: So are you saying that since the case that gcd > 1, it's not valid anyway, and the result will still say it's invalid?

Comment: A Jacobi algorithm switches the intermediate result between +1 and -1. When it has finished and and $\gcd > 1$ the intermediate result is invalid and the final result is zero. See e.g. Cohen, A Course in Computational Number Theory, Algorithms 1.4.10 or 1.4.11.